# How do I Disable OneNote Upgrade Message?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

How do I stop the `download new version of onenote from onenote.com` message?

I will never upgrade from OneNote 2010 to 2013. I want to disable that message permanently.

From my searching it appears that the message comes from an update but which one?

Comment: Do you wish to disable this message for only OneNote 2010 or for all of Office 2010? What is your Windows version?

Comment: Since the original user may not come back I'll answer - To my knowledge, the dialog box doesn't appear in any office application other than OneNote. If I'm wrong, someone please correct me - I suppose system-wide would be preferable but I'll take what I can get. OS is Windows 7, though I believe the popup appears regardless of OS.

Comment: You tried this? For Outlook but may work across Office: https://www.outlook-tips.net/tips/office-2013-upgrade-banner/

Comment: There is supposed to be the following: OneNote, click File---options---Trust center—Trust center settings---Privacy options—Uncheck (Allow office to connect to the internet) and click Ok.  The issue is it depends on the updates that have been made to your OneNote.  Please let me know if this works.  I can search for registry functions to do the same fo you.

Comment: Does anyone actually even have OneNote 2010 Installed that can answer us if something works?

Comment: I do. I'll try the upgrade banner trick shortly. @Jeff, the 'connect to the internet' checkbox was removed from office long ago - and isn't an ideal solution in any case, as that would disable a wide swath of functionality.

Comment: @Fopedush if you could add a screenshot of this to the question it would be helpful.  I would also love to see this registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\OneNote

Comment: Try in menu  `File -> Help`, under `Click-to-run product updates` to set `Update Options -> Disable updates`.

Comment: I'm sorry @harrymc, I've had a sort of family emergency over the last few days and haven't been able to try the registry key. It's also a little tricky to test. because the popup nag messages only comes up once or twice a month. I need to put together a VM that I can revert to get the message to come up more reliably. If an answer is found, I'll re-open the bounty and award it appropriately.

Comment: @Jeff I'll add a shot of that registry key as well as one of the popup itself as soon as I can.

Comment: Hello there, I'm back! :) btw I found solution. registry tip above was not related to this, but it gave me a good hint: dig out registry keys. check my answer and notify me whether it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

For who are in hurry: just copy below block and save it as .reg file, like "disable notification.reg". then open it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\OneNote\General]
"VersionUpgradeDisplayed"=dword:ffffffff
```

original post:

---

### Solution

Open Registry Editor(Regedit.exe)

Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\OneNote\General
and edit value of VersionUpgradeDisplayed to FFFFFFFF.
[image: value of HKCU...\OneNote\General]

In the image, I removed other values except VersionUpgradeDisplayed, but actually you may see other values.

This key is applied to current user. So you have to repeat this for each user (if you have).

---

### Details

"VersionUpgradeDisplayed" value seems to store last date displayed upgrade message. To test, change the value to 0 (instead of your value/FFFFFFFF). Open onenote and it displayes upgrade message. Back to registry editor and press refresh(F5). Then you can find the value is changed to positive integer(some number>0).

I'm not sure its format but two things are clear: First, great number means later date. Second, onenote compare it with current date when it runs, and display upgrade meesage if the value is small enough (and update the value after displaying).

So, to disable upgrade message we have to set very big number to this value and FFFFFFFF is max value we can get.